# Nest.js and TypeORM: Difficulty retrieving nested objects when querying over multiple joined tables

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, has-and-belongs-to-many, nestjs-typeorm

I faced this issue when I get data from over 3 joined tables via TypeORM in Nest.js.
Here are 3 entities:

```
export class TableA  {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Index({ unique: true })
    @ApiProperty()
    tableAId: number;

    @OneToMany((type) => TableB, (tableB) => tableB.tableA, { nullable: true })
    @ApiProperty({ type: 'object', description: 'TableB[]' })
    tableBs: TableB[];

    static findWithMinimalRelations(tableCId: string): SelectQueryBuilder<TableA> {
        return (
            this.createQueryBuilder('tableA')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('tableA.tableBs', 'tableB', '"tableB"."tableCId" = :tableCId', {tableCId})
        );
    }
}

export class TableB  {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Index({ unique: true })
    @ApiProperty()
    tableBId: number;

    
    @Column('enum', { enum: Option, default: Option.default })
    @ApiProperty({ enum: Option, default: Option.default })
    option: Option;

    @ManyToOne((type) => TableC, (tableC) => tableC.tableBs)
    @Index({ unique: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'tableCId', referencedColumnName: 'tableCId' })
    @ApiProperty({ description: 'TableC', type: 'object' })
    tableC: TableC;

    @ManyToOne((type) => TableA, (tableA) => tableA.tableBs)
    @Index({ unique: true })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'tableAId', referencedColumnName: 'tableAId' })
    @ApiProperty({ description: 'TableA', type: 'object' })
    tableA: TableA;

}

export class TableC {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Index({ unique: true })
    @ApiProperty()
    tableCId: number;

    @OneToMany((type) => TableC, (tableB) => tableB.tableC, { nullable: true })
    @ApiProperty({ type: 'object', description: 'TableC[]' })
    tableBs: TableC[];
}
```

When I call `findWithMinimalRelations` of `TableA` method, it generates below query.

```
SELECT
    "tableA"."tableAId" AS "tableA_tableAId"
    "tableB"."tableBId" AS "tableB_tableBId",
    "tableB"."option" AS "tableB_option",
    "tableB"."tableC" AS "tableB_tableC",
    "tableB"."tableAId" AS "tableB_tableAId"
FROM
    "tableA" "tableA"
    LEFT JOIN "account_tableA" "tableB" ON "tableB"."tableAId" = "tableA"."tableAId"
    AND (
        "tableB"."tableAId" = "tableA"."tableAId"
        AND "tableB"."tableC" = $1
    )
```

If I run this query, I can find the result matched with condition.
But the result of `findWithMinimalRelations` has empty `tableBs`.

When I call `findWithMinimalRelations` function, I want to get the result has `tableBs`.